# How to get Javascript to display specific data based on HTML form value

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, forms

I have an html form that has a drop down list of four names.

```js
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = showStudents;
    }

    function showStudents(){
        if(document.getElementById("mary jones").value == "mary jones"){
            document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = "Mary Jones";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("jane doe").value == "jane doe"){
            document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = "Jane Doe";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("henry miller").value == "henry miller"){
            document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = "Henry Miller";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("john smith").value == "john smith"){
            document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = "John Smith";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="students">
<form id="getStudent" action="" method="GET">
    <select name="students">
        <option value="john smith" id="john smith">John Smith</option>
        <option value="jane doe" id="jane doe">Jane Doe</option>
        <option value="henry miller" id="henry miller">Henry Miller</option>
        <option value="mary jones" id="mary jones">Mary Jones</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

When I click submit a Javascript function is called and I want to display the name of the student I chose but it only displays the results of the first if statement. My thought is that I need to pass in the value of the form data into the function but not sure how to do that. Here's the javascript code I've come up.

Comment: Please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: `document.getElementById("mary jones").value == "mary jones"` is always `true`. The value of an option never changes. The other conditions are never checked.

Comment: You can use element.getAttribute to get the name via the element my guess is you only get the first value because the first value always returns true with your setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the selected option - currently, it's only going to set it to "Mary Jones", because the value of the `<option id="mary jones" value="mary jones">` is always going to be "Mary Jones". Use the `.value` property of the `<select>` element to get the selected option's value:

```
function showStudents() {
    var selected = document.getElementById("getStudent")["students"].value;
    var output = document.getElementById("students");
    if (selected == "mary jones") {
        output.innerHTML = "Mary Jones";
    } else if (selected == "jane doe") {
        output.innerHTML = "Jane Doe";
    } else if (selected == "henry miller") {
        output.innerHTML = "Henry Miller";
    } else {
        output.innerHTML = "John Smith";
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that you cannot have a space in an ID name - so your `<option>`s should look like this instead:

```
<option value="mary jones" id="maryJones">Mary Jones</option>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for. I was confusing myself with all the element id's.

Comment: No problem whatsoever @nick_eagles

Comment: also thanks for pointing out the spaces in the id name. i didn't catch that first time around

Comment: Also no problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selected `option` from the `options` for the `select`, then display the text content.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("submit").onclick = showStudents;
}

function showStudents( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var selectField = document.querySelector("select");
  var displayText = selectField.options[ selectField.selectedIndex ].innerText;
  document.getElementById("students").innerText = displayText;
}
```

```html
<div id="students"></div>
<form id="getStudent" action="" method="GET">
  <select name="students">
    <option value="john smith" id="john smith">John Smith</option>
    <option value="jane doe" id="jane doe">Jane Doe</option>
    <option value="henry miller" id="henry miller">Henry Miller</option>
    <option value="mary jones" id="mary jones">Mary Jones</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Many issues with your code:

First: Avoid giving duplicate IDs to different elements. An ID should/must be unique across all HTML. No two elements shall have the same ID. Because if you do that, you will get un-expected results if you call `.getElementById()`.

Second: There is no need to give ids to `<option>` elements, unless you really have to. In your case, there is no benefit of doing that.

Third: Even if you need to assign different IDs to `<option>` elements, avoid spaces in the id string, because that will also lead to undesirable results.

Third: If you want to only print the selected value, you don't need an if-then statement everywhere to check for every possible value. Use if-then only if you will handle each case differently. In your case, a switch statement will make your code more readable and shorter.

I have made some changes to your code to reflect on the points I mentioned above.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("submit").onclick = showStudents;
}

function showStudents() {

  var n = document.getElementById("sel_students");
  var name = n.options[n.selectedIndex].value;
  var output = document.getElementById("div_students");

  output.innerHTML = name;

  switch (name) {
    case "mary jones":
      output.innerHTML += " <br> Hi Mary..";
      break;
    case "jane doe":
      output.innerHTML += " <br> Good bye Jane";
      break;
    case "henry miller":
      output.innerHTML += "<br> Good afternoon";
      break;
    case "john smith":
      output.innerHTML += "<br> no pokahontis here";
      break;
  }


}
```

```html
<div id="div_students">
  <form id="form_students" action="" method="GET">
    <select name="students" id="sel_students">
      <option value="john smith">John Smith</option>
      <option value="jane doe">Jane Doe</option>
      <option value="henry miller">Henry Miller</option>
      <option value="mary jones">Mary Jones</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to do like this

```js
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = showStudents;
    }

    function showStudents(){
        document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = document.getElementById("student-list").value;
    }
```

```html
<div id="students">
<form id="getStudent" action="" method="GET">
    <select name="students" id="student-list">
        <option value="john smith" id="john smith">John Smith</option>
        <option value="jane doe" id="jane doe">Jane Doe</option>
        <option value="henry miller" id="henry miller">Henry Miller</option>
        <option value="mary jones" id="mary jones">Mary Jones</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful for the OP and future visitors if you explained the mistake the OP made and how your solution works. *"Please try to do like this"* is not a useful description of your solution.

Comment: Well, the idea is to work with the `select` field instead of its child elements. The `value` attribut of a `select` DOM element will contain the contents of the `value`-attribute of the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jquery?

get it by `id`

```
var value = $('select#dropDownId option:selected').val();
```

Comment: Yes exactly why dont you use a complete Library for something being accomplishable with Vanilla JS

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="students">
<form id="getStudent" action="" method="GET">
    <select name="students" id="students_value">
        <option value="john smith">John Smith</option>
        <option value="jane doe">Jane Doe</option>
        <option value="henry miller">Henry Miller</option>
        <option value="mary jones">Mary Jones</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>

function showStudents(){
    var selected = document.getElementById("students_value");
    document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = selected;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.